# How to check if only specific columns are non-NA

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have a `data.frame` that has `NA` values in some of the columns. I want to select only those rows which have specific columns that are not `NA`, but may have `NA` on all of its other columns.

So select from this data:

```
dat <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 4, NA, NA), 
                  y = c(2, NA, 3, 5, 4), 
                  z = c(NA, NA, NA, 4, 4),
                  p = c(NA, 4, NA, 3, 4))
   x  y  z  p
1  1  2 NA NA
2  2 NA NA  4
3  4  3 NA NA
4 NA  5  4  3
5 NA  4  4  4
```

these rows:

```
   x  y  z  p 
1  1  2 NA NA
2  4  3 NA NA
```

Comment: What is the expected result from your example?

Comment: Column `x` has non-NA values in the first 2 _rows_, not columns.

Comment: sorry, I have edited the question. I want only those two rows with NA values on all its other columns except for the first two columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your data

```
dat <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 4, NA, NA), 
                  y = c(2, NA, 3, 5, 4), 
                  z = c(NA, NA, NA, 4, 4),
                  p = c(NA, 4, NA, 3, 4))
```

you can select rows for which first column is not NA and second column is not NA:

```
> dat[!is.na(dat[,'x']) & !is.na(dat[,'y']),]
  x y  z  p
1 1 2 NA NA
3 4 3 NA NA
```

Comment: Seems like you would need to add more logical requirements to satisfy the requirement that all other columns be NA.

Comment: @42-, my reading of "but may have NA on all of its other columns." is that rows with all NA in the other columns are fine but not necessary.

Comment: That's not what the questions says in comments made (as of this moment) 19 yours ago.

Answer (score 2):

```
mycols = c("x", "y")
dat[Reduce("&", data.frame(!is.na(dat[names(dat) %in% mycols]))) &
        Reduce("&", data.frame(is.na(dat[!names(dat) %in% mycols]))),]
#  x y  z  p
#1 1 2 NA NA
#3 4 3 NA NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `complete.cases` with

```
dat[complete.cases(dat[, c(1, 2)]) &
            rowSums(is.na(dat[, -c(1, 2)])) == ncol(dat[, -c(1, 2)]), ]
```

Comment: That might satisfy the first requirement, but not the second.

Comment: Thanks @42, you are right since _all other columns must be NA_. It should be OK when adding `rowSums`.

Answer (score 0):

A solution using the `filter_at` function from `dplyr`. We can put the column names in `vars` and the selective condition in `all_vars`, which means all the variables need to meet the condition. After that, we can select other columns except `x` and `y` to be all `NA`.

```
library(dplyr)

dat2 <- dat %>%
  filter_at(vars(x, y), all_vars(!is.na(.))) %>%
  filter_at(vars(-x, -y), all_vars(is.na(.)))
dat2
#   x y  z  p
# 1 1 2 NA NA
# 2 4 3 NA NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution with `dplyr` using `filter`:

```
dat %>%
  filter(!is.na(x) & !is.na(y))
```

**Result:**

```
  x y  z  p
1 1 2 NA NA
2 4 3 NA NA
```

Answer (score 0):

Interpreting that you do not require that columns 3 and 4 must have NA, but that this is permissible, here is another base R solution with `lapply` and `Reduce`:

```
dat[!Reduce("|", lapply(dat[1:2], is.na)),]
  x y  z  p
1 1 2 NA NA
3 4 3 NA NA
```

If the desired outcome additionally requires that columns 3 and 4 must only contain NAs (which is a pretty strange request), then you could add a similar statement to get this result.

```
dat[!Reduce("|", lapply(dat[1:2], is.na)) & Reduce("&", lapply(dat[3:4], is.na)),]
```